# Best way to take out keys with invalid (NaN, blank, etc) values from an object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got a short search form that a user fills out. There will be multiple search queries that will go into MongoDB:

The form creates a variable called `searchParams` that may look like this:

```
var searchParams = {
  city: "Springfield",
  bedrooms: 3,
  bathrooms: 2
};
```

I then have a function that takes the searchParams as an argument and queries Mongo using it:

```
var searchListings = function(searchParams){
  return db.MyListings.find(searchParams).fetch();
}

db.MyListings.find( {city: "Springfield", bedrooms: 3, bathrooms: 2} ).fetch();
```

This is all well and good for a complete `searchParams` object, but if the user doesn't fill out parts of the form and the object turns out to be this:

```
var searchParams = {
  city: "",
  bedrooms: NaN,
  bathrooms: 3
};
```

The query fails. It tries to literally search for a property with a city of "" and a bedroom of NaN.

What I want the query to be in the case of this object is just:

```
  db.MyListings.find( {bathrooms: 3} ).fetch();
```

I can go through each key one by one and check for NaN conditions and "" conditions and somehow remove the key from the `searchParams` object (I guess I'm like sterilizing the object?) but I was wondering if there was a more intelligent way to go about taking out the keys with invalid values?

I've got `underscore` installed.

UPDATE: This project is currently using Meteor 0.9.1. Meteor uses Underscore 1.0.0, which is why the below did not work:

The following doesn't seem to be working:

```
searchParams = {
  bathrooms: 3,
  bedrooms: NaN,
  city: "",
  exteriorSize: NaN,
  interiorSize: NaN,
  price: 0
};

console.log(searchParams);

newSearchParams = _.omit(searchParams, function(val) { 
  return !val;
});

console.log(newSearchParams); // exactly the same as searchParams
```

And if I do this:

```
searchParams = {
  bathrooms: 3,
  bedrooms: NaN,
  city: "",
  exteriorSize: NaN,
  interiorSize: NaN,
  price: 0
};

console.log(searchParams);

newSearchParams = _.pick(searchParams, function(val) { 
  return !!val;
});

console.log(newSearchParams); // blank object
```

Comment: Which version of `underscore` is used?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8krqLc2o/) with 1.7.0.

Comment: Hmmm... It's whatever version Meteor 0.9.1 ships with.

Comment: Bah, Meteor's Underscore uses 1.0.0. I'm wondering if I force 1.7.0 will I break Meteor since it relies on Underscore.

Comment: Well, I've added the "plain way" into my answer; as this question will probably be helpful for someone else, I'll leave the "underscore way" there as well (as it's more concise and readable).

Comment: As for underscore upgrade, I don't remember any radical change in underscore API. But yeah, one should be careful with such things. )

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think it may be safest to leave Meteor's Underscore the way it is. From the Meteor docs: "We have slightly modified the way Underscore differentiates between objects and arrays in collection functions. The original Underscore logic is to treat any object with a numeric length property as an array (which helps it work properly on NodeLists). In Meteor's version of Underscore, objects with a numeric length property are treated as objects if they have no prototype (specifically, if x.constructor === Object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `underscore 1.7.0+`, you can easily filter the query object with [**_.pick()**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
searchParams = _.pick(searchParams, function(val) { 
  return !!val;
});
```

... that'll create an object with only those properties that were assigned truthy values.

You can do the same thing, but in a slightly different way, with [**_.omit()**](http://underscorejs.org/#omit):

```
searchParams = _.omit(searchParams, function(val) { 
  return !val;
});
```

In this case, all the properties with falsy values will be dropped.

---

For the completeness sake, here's a vanilla JS way:

```
var filteredSearchParams = {};
for (var prop in searchParams) {
  if (searchParams.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !!searchParams[prop]) {
    filteredSearchParams[prop] = searchParams[prop];
  }
}
```