# Is it safe to upgrade Meteor's Underscore to 1.7.0?

Tags: meteor, underscore.js

This is coming from this topic:

[Best way to take out keys with invalid (NaN, blank, etc) values from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738420/best-way-to-take-out-keys-with-invalid-nan-blank-etc-values-from-an-object)

I couldn't get the commenter's underscore method to work because Meteor only uses Underscore 1.0.0, and certain functions don't work like Underscore 1.7.0 does.

From the Meteor Docs:

> We have slightly modified the way Underscore differentiates between objects and arrays in collection functions. The original Underscore logic is to treat any object with a numeric length property as an array (which helps it work properly on NodeLists). In Meteor's version of Underscore, objects with a numeric length property are treated as objects if they have no prototype (specifically, if x.constructor === Object.

So it appears that Meteor has changed Underscore a tad.

Has anyone here forced Meteor to use Underscore 1.7.0 in their app and gotten any weirdness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [history](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commits/devel/packages/underscore/underscore.js) of the underscorejs package in the meteor repository, you'll see that they actually changed the underscorejs library instead of [monkeypatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it. ([here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/a4b9dd52f30eac37bb597aba97a40e5e7596192c) and [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/bab936eac99004b6cd14b4ed8b279862e2d7e606))

So I would strongly recommend against upgrading the underscorejs version.

If you really really must upgrade, I suggest trying to apply the commits of the meteor version to the latest version. Luckily the package does contain [tests](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/fb446cbe168f5c075d572531561818cffb3de80a) for the fixes the meteor team did. So start with upgrading the underscorejs file and then running the tests if they all pass you're probably good to go.

Comment: And if you do go through all this trouble, [send them a patch](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1009)